# HttpResponseException is not handled in a webapi controller in area

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have two webapi controllers in my MVC 5 project, one in the main domain:

```
namespace VincConsultancy.Controllers
{
    public class QuestionGroupController : ApiController
    {
        //...

        public IEnumerable<SAQQuestionGroup> Get(int id = 0)
        {
            var groups = (from g in repository.SAQQuestionGroups
                         where g.RequirementId == id
                         select g).ToList();
            if (groups.Count == 0)
            {
                string message = string.Format("Groups with Req id = {0} not found", id);
                throw new HttpResponseException(
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message)
                );
            }
            return groups;
        }
    }
}
```

The other one in the area domain:

```
namespace VincConsultancy.Areas.admin.Controllers
{
    public class SAQGroupsController : ApiController
    {
        //...
        public IEnumerable<SAQGroup> Get(int id = 0)
        {
            var groups = (from g in this.dbCnxt.SAQQustnGroups
                          where g.RequirementId == id
                          select g).ToList();
            if (groups.Count == 0)
            {
                string message = string.Format("Groups with Req id = {0} not found", id);
                throw new HttpResponseException(
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message)
                );
            }
            return groups;
        }
    }
}
```

In both controllers, I return error messages by throwing HttpResponseException. Visual Studio pauses the execution at the line of 'throw new HttpResponseException' only in the controller in the admin area, saying an exception occurs but was not handled by user code, that doesnt affect the functionality though, i just need to press the continue button every time. However it doesnt happen to the other controller. So, I am wondering if there is some mechanism handling the exceptions in main domain automatically. The throw-exception line is not supposed to be caught by my code, how should I get rid of visual studio breaking there?

Comment: Don't know for sure why would it break when one is thrown and the other is not when both are exactly the same type (unless you have some code that handles the exception in the main controller). but you might want to check this post and play with the exception settings: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: Could you try and check if the code in both methods is hit, try using debug with some break points in the first line of the methods, then step through(step over or into if necessary) the code line by line. I suspect the code in the other method is not being hit or it does not reach the condition of generating the exception. One more thing, before doing this, I guess you could try to clean and rebuild your solution.